# Compiler Error C2079 | uses undefined class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class login_register;
class customer;
class cook;
class admin 
{
protected:
    int choice;
    string myText;
public:
  /* admin(int x, string y) {
        choice = x;
        myText = y;
    }*/
    void menu_selection()
    {
        ifstream MyReadFile("filename.txt");
        while (getline(MyReadFile, myText))
        {
            cout << myText << endl;
        }
        MyReadFile.close();
       
    }
};

class login_register : public admin 
{
protected:
    int countcu, countco;
    string usercu, passcu, ucu, pcu;
    string regusercu, regpasscu;
    string userco, passco, uco, pco;
    string reguserco, regpassco;

private:
    customer obj;
public:
   /* friend customer;
    friend void customer::registrcu();*/
    
    
    void choice_selection()
    {
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
```

//error is here I want to call the child class function
//customer register

```
           obj.registrcu();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            //customer login 
            /*void customer::logincu();*/
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            //cook register
            void registr();
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            //customer login
            void registr();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " !!!!!!!!! invalid option eneterd !!!!!!!!! " << endl;
            Sleep(1750);
            system("cls");
            admin::menu_selection();
            login_register::choice_selection();
        }
    }
};

class customer : public login_register
{
public:
    friend class login_register;
    void registrcu()
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Enter the username :";
        cin >> regusercu;
        cout << "\nEnter the password :";
        cin >> regpasscu;

        ofstream reg("database.txt", ios::app);
        reg << regusercu << ' ' << regpasscu << endl;
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nRegistration Sucessful\n";
        /*main();*/
    }
    void logincu()
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Please enter the following details" << endl;
        cout << "USERNAME :";
        cin >> usercu;
        cout << "PASSWORD :";
        cin >> passcu;

        ifstream input("database.txt");
        while (input >> ucu >> pcu)
        {
            if (ucu == usercu && pcu == passcu)

            {
                countcu = 1;
                system("cls");
            }
        }
        input.close();
        if (countcu == 1)
        {
            cout << "\nHello" << usercu << "\n<LOGIN SUCCESSFUL>\nThanks for logging in..\n";
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
            /* main();*/
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nLOGIN ERROR\nPlease check your username and password\n";
            /* main();*/
        }
    }
};
class cook : public login_register
{

};

int main() {
    
    
    admin x;
    x.menu_selection();
    login_register o;
    o.choice_selection();
    

    /*system("CLS");*/
}
```

I want to run this function registrcu(); from class customer in class login_register but I wont be able to do that.The main thing I want is to call child class function in parent class and that parent class is login_register while login_register is also a parent class of admin .

Comment: There's no guarantee that a `login_register` is a `customer`.  It's generally a bad sign if a class has to know about its specific children.  Why not use a `virtual register()`?

Comment: `else if (choice == 3) { ...  void registr();` note that the `void registr();` here is declaring a function not calling one.

Comment: Kindly check the first if condition If it runs then all the conditions will run with the same scenario